# Draw a sprite when a key is pressed in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I'm working with LibGDX. How can I draw a sprite when a key is pressed? I have tried with the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.X)) {
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: can you add more details? "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: what I mean is that with that code the sprite is not drawn and I don't get it why

Comment: can you write your whole code

Answer (score 1):

You could have a boolean that you set to true when the key is pressed in your update method:

```
 boolean drawSprite;
 if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.X)) {
      drawSprite = true;
 }
```

And then in your render method:

```
batch.begin();
if(drawSprite == true) {
 sprite.draw(batch);
}
batch.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `Sprite` class from libgdx and the sprite you created is working fine? And the only problem is you cannot show the sprite when a key is pressed.

```
@Override
public void update() {

    // the input is pressed once even you are still holding the button.
    if(Gdx.input.isJustKeyPressed(Input.Keys.X)) {
        sprite.setVisible(true);
    }

    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();

}
```

Comment: should I add it necessary in the `update()` mehtod?

Comment: @MagnusSchuldiner yes, if you are gonna toggle show and hide of sprite